# Should I take time off and learn or get a job and learn more slowly?

Tags: developer

I have a confusing question. I have been working as a front end developer for almost 5 years now, for a few of the high-traffic well known websites in the market. I have an in-depth knowledge of full stack front end tech, except for angular.js, which at the moment is getting a god-like status.

Right now, I do not have a job. My last workplace decided to hire experienced angular.js front enders and fire my team. If I take 3 months off and learn it on my own and then come back looking for work, do you think the gap will look bad? Or should I go for another front end role and learn angular.js on the side? Just to note that pretty much all front end around me seems to need angular...

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, learning and job hunting aren't mutually exclusive.

I'd argue that a job is, indeed, more important than a skill-learning break, in this case. Look for a job *and* learn angular.js right now.

Like you say, gaps seem odd, and jobs don't always jump in front of you straight away. It's probably better to learn while looking than wait for three months before starting to look - both for your pocket, and for your cv.